# navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition throwing error on android for IBM MF - 7.1.0.00.20170330-0917

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

Recently I have applied MobileFirst Platform Studio 0917 fix pack from then onwards unable to get current position on android devices by using "navigator.gelocation.getCurrentPosition".

Comment: On the same device was it working fine before the upgrade ? Also, has the device been upgraded ? OS ?

Comment: Also, you mentioned in the problem title that an error is being thrown, but I do not see the error mentioned in the description.  Could you provide the error and perhaps a logcat file?  Thanks.